# How Do I Use Scrollspy when I have links on the page and off the page?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I have an application with a landing page that has many sections, and use Scrollspy for the smooth scrolling effect in the page. At the end of my navigation items I have a call to action button that takes the user to another page. However, because it's in my navigation items, when the page loads, Scrollspy is throwing an error on the link to another page.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://example.com/page2
```

Is there anything I can do to tell scrollspy to ignore that link or is there some other way to get rid of that error? Thanks!

Here is the code I am using to initialize scrollspy:

```
(function ($) {

    'use strict';

    // SmoothLink
    function initSmoothLink() {
        $('.nav-item a').on('click', function(event) {
            var $anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 0
            }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    // StickyMenu
    function initStickyMenu() {
        $(window).on('scroll',function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 50) {
                $(".sticky").addClass("stickyadd");
            } else {
                $(".sticky").removeClass("stickyadd");
            }
        });
    }

    // Scrollspy
    function initScrollspy() {
        $("#navbarCollapse").scrollspy({
            offset: 70
        });
    }

    //MFPVideo
    function initMFPVideo() {
        $('.video_play').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,
            fixedContentPos: false
        });
    }

    // Back To Top
    function initBackToTop() {
        $(window).on('scroll',function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.back_top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.back_top').fadeOut();
            }
        }); 
        $('.back_top, .footer_logo_link').on('click',function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
            return false;
        });
    }

    function init() {
        initSmoothLink();
        initStickyMenu();
        initScrollspy();
        initMFPVideo();
        initBackToTop();
    }

    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
        init();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you post your code that you are using to initialize scrollspy and the smooth scrolling effect?

Comment: Sure, no problem @imvain2

Answer (score 0):

You can add in if statement to check if the href has a hash. If it doesn't have one, then it will just proceed as normal.

```
function initSmoothLink() {
        $('.nav-item a').on('click', function(event) {
            var $anchor = $(this);
            if (this.hash !== "") {
               $('html, body').stop().animate({
                   scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 0
               }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
               event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: The only trouble is that this event only fires when a link is clicked. The error arrives on page load. It doesn't seem like any of the init functions fire on load.

Comment: The error is happening in the initScrollspy. I can't find a way to exclude the item.

Comment: You could always append the link via JavaScript after you initialize scrollspy that way scrollspy doesn’t see it.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollspy looks for all `a` tags in given container, takes `href` attribute and uses it's value as jQuery selector. Here is the possible solution using JS:

```
<a href="#page2" id="page2" onclick="location.href='https://example.com/page2'">Page 2</a>
```

Setting `href` and `id` is required in your case if you don't want to add additional checks in `initSmoothLink()` function.